# Modifying owner property of multiple directories

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Looking at the directory resource the owner property is a string and path is also a string. How can I change the owner of multiple directories using a single resource block assuming the directory already exsits?

```
directory '/etc/apache2' do
  owner 'root'
end
```

Comment: write a custom resource for that - https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html

where you pass paths and their owners as an array attribute. Anyways there is no such availability in chef default directory resource.

Answer (score 2):

you can't, they each take a single value.  You could do this:

```
{'/path/to/one' => 'root', '/path/to/another' => 'otherUser'}.each_pair do |path, username|
  directory path do
    owner username
  end
end
```